# How to add br when a pug var as return line?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I use express and pug when I inject a text var in my pug file they did not have any return line. While the string contains many \n. So how to replace line return by br in pug ?

this is my var injection :

```js
myTextString=
`
Hey
I'm
A String
`;

this.res.render('./membres/DisplayMember', { candidature:myTextString});
```

and here is my pug code :

```
p(style="text-align:justify")=candidature
```

and that my output:

```html
<p>Hey I'm A String</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pug's syntax to display raw html is `!{variable}`.

Your JS:

```
myTextString=
`
Hey
I'm
A String
`.replace(/\n/g, '<br>');

this.res.render('./membres/DisplayMember', { candidature:myTextString});
```

Pug:

```
p(style="text-align:justify") !{candidature}
```

Comment: It's work :o
Thanks, I don't know that !{var} don't escape HTML tag

Comment: Very useful. Helped me a lot. But be careful because of security reason.